# Does this integration problem make sense?

Tags: calculus

I ran across this problem in my calculus notes: $$\frac{d}{dt} \int^2_x (2x+5)^2 dt$$
and I'm a bit confused. I'm wondering if I wrote it down incorrectly and that some $x$'s should be $t$'s or vice versa. Otherwise, I don't understand how I would solve it, if it's even possible.

Thanks! Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Having the same variable in the limit, the derivative and the integral is guaranteed confusion.

Comment: Talk about a tricky problem! :-) its going on my next quiz.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make sense, but it's rather uninteresting because $(2x+5)^2$ does not depend on $t$ and so $$\int_x^2(2x+5)^2\,\mathrm dt=(2x+5)^2(2-x)$$
which does not depend on $t$ and so if you derive it you get $0$. Maybe it should have been
$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx}\int_x^2(2t+5)^2\,\mathrm dt
$$
which is somewhat more interesting.

Comment: Can you show me how $\int_x^2(2x+5)^2\,\mathrm dt=(2x+5)^2(2-x)$?

Comment: $$\int_x^2(2x+5)^2\,\mathrm dt=(2x+5)^2\int_x^2 1\,\mathrm dt=(2x+5)^2(2-x)$$

Comment: Maybe the problem is the way you originally interpret it with the final answer being zero. Its like how I would ask $\frac{d}{dx}e^{\pi}+\pi^e$ just to test their comprehension. Do they really know what's happening or did they learn to just mimic like a monkey?

Comment: @FixedPoint: That's a good point! I was just certain that it must have been a typo, so I gave the answer without thinking about it. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

It might be

$\frac{d}{dx}\int_x^2(2t+5)^2 dt$.